# Можно ли сделать inline keyboard со встроенной URL ссылкой в aiogram?

Tags: telegram, aiogram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я нажимал на кнопку "Отзывы" меня перекидывало на другой телеграм канал. это возможно?

Comment: `button = InlineKeyboardButton('Отзывы', url='https://google.com')` . Перед тем как завдавать вопросы сначала поищите информация в документации https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/inline_keyboard_button.html

Comment: Да это походу один и тот же тип регается, и вопросы задает одни и те же

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato надо отдельный SO для ботоводов)))

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно задал вопрос. Имел ввиду клавиатуру с кнопками снизу, а не инлайн кнопки. Уже понял что так сделать нельзя

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/783108)